# Random Number Generator With the Random Header

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to make a random number generator (as the title says) but whenever I try something with an integer, it returns the same number. Here is some code that apparently works. (uses the  header and everything else)

```
default_random_engine e;
cout << e<< endl;
```

but when i try it, I will only get the number 1.
I have tried this with the mac terminal, clion, and Visual Studio.
I really don't know what to do.

Comment: May be read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) before using it?

Comment: `cout << e()`, not `e`. Just a typo, read the docs more carefully.

Comment: The problem could be he does not understand the docs. The cited page does not explain what `operator()` means in this context. The top result of searching for `default_random_engine` does not offer an example of using the generator.

Answer (score 1):

[operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/linear_congruential_engine/operator%3C%3C/) writes **textual representation of the object's current state**.

To get the next number you call `operator()` so:

`cout << e();`